# Salesforce Marketing Cloud Connect: Synchronization interval and Conflicts

Tags: marketing-cloud

**Background**

- I've installed the Marketing Cloud connector in my salesforce org.
- In Salesforce over 1 Mio contacts are present
- Salesforce is used as a data source

**Question**

- If I add a new field to ExactTarget how long does it take to synchronize it to Marketing Cloud (for a mio records)?
- How does the integration handle conflicts (imagine I'm updating a record in Sales and Marketing cloud at the same time)

  - What is the interval the synchronization is running?

Comment: Are you using Data Stream?  Adding a field to ExactTarget (SFMC) will not add it to your Salesforce ORG.  There's no synchronization from ExactTarget to your Salesforce ORG.  Data Stream can run every 15 minutes and will update the data on your data extension.  So I don't imagine there being any conflict with that.  http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/connecting_the_clouds/integrating_data_into_your_account_with_data_stream/